# Error con GET y Fetch en NODE

Tags: nodejs, api, fetch, get

buenas me encuentro haciendo un GET con fetch

```
        var id = [
            '1313',
            '411241',
            '6466456',
            '766767',
            '767675',
          ];
        for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            fetch(`https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/${id[i]}/profile?hapikey=${ hapikey }`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                return res.status(200).send(data)
    
                            
                })
                .catch((error) =>{
                    console.log("Error al encontrar los contactos")
                    console.log(error);
                    return res.status(500).send(error)
                    
                })
                
                
          }
```

me han pedido extraer 5 id con una api, pero al momento de dar send en post man tan solo me trae el primer id y en los otros 4 me arroja el siguiente error

```
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Encontre una solucion que era borrando `.send(data)` pero solo me imprime los datos en la consola de visual, pero no lo imprime en postman. Estoy super colgado ya que soy nuevo programando.

Comment: Postman solo te trae 1 ID porque ese fecth está trayendo los contactos de 1 ID. Postman no puede ejecutar un for, y en tu método fetch, es válido para 1 ID a la vez.

Comment: habría alguna forma o programa que pudiera leer mi for. Gracias de todos modos por la respuesta

Comment: Ese creo que no es el enfoque. Dentro de tu API debería haber un link para obtener todos los usuarios y no uno en específico.